# Entry undefined in HashMap iteration loop

Tags: java, loops, dictionary, iterator

I've done the following dozens of times:

```
for(Map.Entry<Key, WordSet> entry : topWordCountSets.entrySet()) {
    Key currentKey = (entry.getKey());
}
```

However, `entry` in `entry.getKey()` is apparently undefined. I don't define it anywhere outside the loop, so there are no collisions.

Here's more code (the get best algorithm is not completed, due to the fact that entry is not defined.):

```
package hangman;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Partitions {
    private int _wordLength = 2;
    private WordSet _L;
    private HashMap<Key, WordSet> _partitions = new HashMap<Key, WordSet>();

    public void initialize(InputStream stream, int wordLength) throws Exception {
        _L = WordSetParser.generate(stream,wordLength);
    }

    private void _partition(char by) throws Exception {
        _partitions.clear();
        Iterator<Word> iterator = _L.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Word nextWord = iterator.next();
            if(nextWord.length() == _wordLength) {
                Key nextKey = new Key(nextWord, by);
                if(!_partitions.containsKey(nextKey)) {
                    _partitions.put(nextKey, new WordSet(_wordLength));
                }
                _partitions.get(nextKey).add(nextWord);    
            }            
        }
    }

    public WordSet getBestPartition(char by) throws Exception {
        //Establish partitions
        _partition(by);

        //Find partitions with greatest number of words
        HashMap<Key, WordSet> topWordCountSets = new HashMap<Key, WordSet>();
        int maxWords = 0;
        for(Map.Entry<Key, WordSet> entry : _partitions.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getValue().size() > maxWords) {
                maxWords = entry.getValue().size();
                topWordCountSets.clear();
                topWordCountSets.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            else if(entry.getValue().size() == maxWords) {
                topWordCountSets.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }

        if(topWordCount.size() == 1)
            return (WordSet)topWordCountSets.values().toArray()[0];
        else {
            //Find partitions with best key
            Key bestKey = null;
            for(Map.Entry<Key, WordSet> entry : topWordCountSets.entrySet()) {
                Key currentKey =  (entry.getKey());
                if(bestKey == null)
                    bestKey = currentKey;
                else if(currentKey.count() == 0 && bestKey.count() != 0)
                    bestKey = currentKey;
                else if(currentKey.count() != bestKey.count())
                    bestKey = () ? bestKey : currentKey;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Open/Close your IDE Clean/Build your Project

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. Also note that the brackets around `entry.getKey()` are pointless.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Luna, the error is 'entry cannot be resolved', asking if I want to create a local variable with the name or a field, I've tried cleaning and building, and I realize the extra parentheses are pointless, they're just left over. I'll post more code momentarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your ternary operator that confuses the compiler :

```
bestKey = () ? bestKey : currentKey;
```

You forgot to put a condition inside the brackets.

I managed to recreate this error with a small example (I actually used a map with different types of Key and Value, but it makes no difference) :

```
  for (Map.Entry<Key, WordSet> entry : topWordCountSets.entrySet ()) {
    Key currentKey = entry.getKey (); // fake error
    Key bestKey = () ? null : null; // real error
  }
```

This makes the compiler show two errors, one for `entry` and one for the `()`. If you fix the `()` error (for example by changing it to `(true)`), both errors go away. I have no idea why the compiler reports an error on `entry`.

Comment: Strange... I tried the same and got only an error at bestKey = () ? bestKey : currentKey; Arch Linux with openjdk. Would be interesting to know which java version the OP had

Comment: @user I don't know, but I recreated it on Java 6 on Eclipse Juno.

Comment: *Bonks head repeatedly against wall* Wow, thanks. I didn't even think to look further. I would have expected a compile error only at the ternary.